# I am trying to work with useQuery in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

When working with the `useQuery` hook in typescript/react I get an error saying `Argument of type '(param: Param) => Promise<any>'` is not assignable to parameter of type `'QueryFunction<IResponsePlanets, QueryKey>'`.

but keep in mind that onSuccess function is working here. even though I get an error

This is the interface for params

```
type Param = {
    pageParam?: undefined;
    queryKey: [string, { page: number }];
}
```

This is the async function

```
const fetchFunction = async (param: Param) => {
    const [key, { page }] = param.queryKey;
    const response = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/planet/?page=${page}`);
    return response.json();
};
```

This is the useQuery hook

```
 const { status, error, data } = useQuery<IResponsePlanets, Error>(["planets", { page: 1 }], fetchFunction, {
     staleTime: 5000,
     onSuccess: () => {
         console.log('working')
     }
 };
```

Comment: please provide a reproduction (e.g. codesandbox), it's hard to say otherwise

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in signature of your `fetchFunction`

```
const fetchFunction = async (param: Param) => {
                                    ^^^^^
    const [key, { page }] = param.queryKey;
    const response = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/planet/?page=${page}`);
    return response.json();
};
```

The argument should be of type `QueryFunctionContext<Param>`